# Why i need to escape () sometimes in sed

Tags: linux, sed, awk

When i use sed and use braces like this

```
sed -re 's/top([0-9]+)//g'
```

1. I works for this but i have seen sometimes i need to escape the braces and sometimes it works without escaping. why is that
2. Why does \w don't work with awk

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the `-r` switch you are using:

```
   -r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

With `-r` the brackets mean a captured group, and to match literal brackets you have to escape them.

Without `-r` it's vice versa.

Consider:

```
$ sed -r 's/foo([0-9]*)/\1/' <<<'foo123'
123
$ sed 's/foo([0-9]*)/\1/' <<<'foo123'
sed: -e expression #1, char 17: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS
$ sed 's/([0-9]*)//' <<<'foo(123)'
foo
$ sed 's/foo\([0-9]*\)/\1/' <<<'foo(123)'
(123)
```

(in the last one the groups matches zero digits)

Answer (score 0):

In the classical regular expressions `sed` uses, you have to backslash the parentheses to give them the special meaning. If your `sed` supports `-r`, it can use "extended" regular expressions, where parentheses have the special meaning *without* backslashes, backslashing them makes them lose the meaning.

`\w` should work in `awk`. What have you tried, what output did you expect and what output did you get?